# ClassNotFoundException when connecting to Mysql with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a simple Java JDBC program at the command line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LoadDriver/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoadDriver.java
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
```

Here's the simple Java program, copied right out of the JDBC docs:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
// Notice, do not import com.mysql.jdbc.*
// or you will have problems!
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, I'm bloody sure my bash shell $ClASSPATH variable is pointed at the correct .jar file. To be sure, I copied the JDBC .jar to the same directory as my program and ran it as follows:

```
java -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver.java
```

I still get the same error.

Edit:

I followed Powerlord's suggestion below, and now I am still getting virtually the same exception.

I entered:

```
javac -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver.java 
java LoadDriver
```

Whether or not I leave the classpath flag on the second command seems not to matter. I am still getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LoadDriver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoadDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your syntax is just wrong here.  Have you already compiled LoadDriver.java using:

```
javac -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver.java ?
```

If so, then you should be able to do :

```
java -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver
```

(Note that I removed the '.java' from the end)

Comment: This was almost right. I also had to add ./ to my classpath. So the final command line was java -classpath ./:./mysql-<whatever>.jar LoadDriver

Comment: Actually, you don't need mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar in your classpath when compiling, because the driver is only needed at runtime (it is loaded by reflection).

Answer (score 2):

Short version:
`javac` requires you to put the .java at the end, `java` requires you to **not** put the .java at the end.

As Jim Garrison noted before he deleted his answer, this command-line to run the program is wrong.

```
java -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver.java
```

This tells Java to load `LoadDriver/java.class`

What you actually want is

```
java -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver
```

Provided of course that you compile it first with

```
javac -classpath ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar LoadDriver.java
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the missing driver, it's the missing LoadDriver class. You need to compile the .java source file to a .class file first:

```
javac LoadDriver.java
```